# Bolding Specific text at Footer

Tags: excel, vba

How to use macro vba excel bolding this specific text at footer? Need some help with thanks first~

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the right footer.  To reference the value of the right footer for the current worksheet in VBA, use:

```
myString = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter
```

I do not know, and you haven't said exactly how "August" is generated.  It could be a constant string, a variable, a macro, etc...

If you wish to bold all month values (i.e. August in this case) in all worksheets, all you need to do is edit your right footer, and place &B directive before and after the month, or whatever generates the month value.

For example:

```
End of Statement : &BAugust&B
```

This change will apply to all sheets, and not just the current sheet.

Comment: If i have using userform then August is follow userform

Comment: `.RightFooter = "&9End of Statement : &""Calibri,Bold" & ExportForm.cbMonth`

Answer (score -1):

when you value the footer with your text, use this construction:

```
YourSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "End of Statement : &""-,Bold""" &  ExportForm.cbMonth.Text
```

Comment: `.RightFooter = "&9End of Statement : &""Calibri,Bold" & ExportForm.cbMonth` this was my userform combobox title

Comment: you are close, you need to add another two quotes following the Bold     
"&9End of Statement : &""Calibri,Bold""" & ExportForm.cbMonth.Text